# Is the volume of a convex polytope efficiently computable from the vertices

Tags: convex-analysis, polytopes

Is there an efficient method to compute the exact volume of a bounded full-dimensional convex polytope, given the coordinates of its vertices (V-representation)?

Comment: How many dimensions?  In low dimensions it's not too bad, but for high-dimensional polytopes there are no very good general algorithms known (but many algorithms with runtimes $n^k$ for fairly large $k$ - e.g., I believe there's an algorithm in $\Theta^*(n^9)$ or something around there.)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki The number of dimensions is high. So the answer is, 'no'.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Can you point out some references for any algorithm that does this?